# Object to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a dictionary by List of object for example

```
public class personne
{
   public string code {get; set;}
   public string ItemName {get;set;}
   public string Adresse {get;set}
}
```

I want to have for each property an element in the dictionary, whose name of the property represents the key and the value is a list of strings which are the values ​​of the list using linq:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> test = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

key = proprety

value = values of property

Comment: Absolutely unclear what do you want. Can you show the object or json you have now, and what object would you like to convert it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what prevents you from building this dictionary manually? This is certainly the most efficient approach(no reflection) and even with more properties not too much work:

```
List<personne> persons = new() { ... };

Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new()
{
   { nameof(personne.code), new(persons.Count) },
   { nameof(personne.ItemName), new(persons.Count) },
   { nameof(personne.Adresse), new(persons.Count) }
};

foreach(var person in persons)
{
    dict[nameof(personne.code)].Add(person.code);
    dict[nameof(personne.ItemName)].Add(person.ItemName);
    dict[nameof(personne.Adresse)].Add(person.Adresse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, in my case where I have an object with more than 15 properties it seems a bit repetitive

Comment: @sam: you could use reflection. But the code would be much less efficient, less readable, more complicated and not compile time safe and future-proof. Btw, i have edited my answer to provide a non-linq version that is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to do this on demand for any object, something like the following will work via reflection:

```
var personne = new Personne 
{ 
    code = "codevalue", 
    ItemName = "ItemNameValue", 
    Adresse = "AdresseValue", 
    Adresses = new List<string> { "AdressesValue" } 
};
var dict = ObjectToDictionary(personne);


public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> ObjectToDictionary<T>(T input)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(properties.Length);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(input);

        if (value is List<string> valueList)
        {
            dict[prop.Name] = valueList;
        }
        else
        {
            dict[prop.Name] = new List<string> { (string)value };
        }
    }
    
    return dict;
}
```

Granted, there is a cost to this and you might want to consider using compiled expressions instead.